# enjoy or enjoyed ? an activity of past

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

1. I didn't **enjoyed** it as much as though I would have
2. I didn't **enjoy** it as much as though I would have

This is about, an activity (to be done in morning) which had been planned\thought of in the night. So when writing about it the next day after the activity was completed, which sentence (1 or 2) is correct ?

context: First person journaling his day

Confusion about: writer is talking about a past activity, so is the use of word *enjoyed* correct ?
and using *enjoy* convert the conversation to be perceived as present tense ?

Please also explain use of which word is correct as well.

Comment: Hello, your question has been asked before.  The verb is "didn't enjoy". Only the auxiliary verb "do" has tense.  The head of the verb phrase is infinitive.